# Why does overlapping I/O become slower on larger files with more I/O operations?

Tags: c++, winapi, overlapped-io

I am trying to understand why this code starts working slower with large 1.8 GB file when *parts* variable is increasing, so more reads and writes are performed in a single iteration. The function is below. In and out files are created with CreateFile() with FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED and FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING flags. Time is measured for 8 KB buffer. Completion routine for reading just increases global variable *g_readers* by one, and completion routine for writing does the same for *g_writers*.

|  | 1 IO | 2 IOs | 4 IOs | 8 IOs | 12 IOs | 16 IOs |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **1.8 GB** | 92 s | 92 s | 59s | 150 s | 268 s | 376 s |
| **121 MB** | 7532 ms | 7484 ms | 4034 ms | 2975 ms | 2197 ms | 2178 ms |
| **4.7 MB** | 289 ms | 274 ms | 171 ms | 121 ms | 100 ms | 78 ms |

[image: 1.8 GB times]

[image: 121 MB times]

[image: 4.7 MB times]

I am using a SATA SSD Samsung 860 evo with NTFS for it. Results with exFAT HDD are just slower, otherwise all the same.

I've read on learn.microsoft.com, that asynchronous IO was intended to use when it is needed to make some IO while making some other calculations, but there is little information on how starting multiple IO operations works.
As far as I understand, when making more reads and writes in a single iteration there shouldn't be dramatic changes, as overall amount of work is the same, as there is no parallelism.
I've tried to start writing in reading completion routine, but there was no measurable changes for all three cases.

```
...
void _copyFileByParts(HANDLE existingFile, HANDLE newFile, DWORD nNumberOfBytesToRead, int parts) {
    fileSize = GetFileSize(existingFile, NULL);
    buff = new BYTE[fileSize];
    newFile = newFile;
    offsets = new DWORD[parts];
    OVERLAPPED* overlapped = new OVERLAPPED[parts];

    for (int i = 0; i < parts; i++) {
        offsets[i] = i * fileSize / nNumberOfBytesToRead / parts * nNumberOfBytesToRead;
        overlapped[i].Internal = NULL;
        overlapped[i].InternalHigh = NULL;
        overlapped[i].hEvent = (HANDLE) i;
        overlapped[i].Offset = offsets[i];
        overlapped[i].OffsetHigh = 0;
    }
    int leftToCopy = fileSize - offsets[parts - 1];

    do {
        g_readers = 0;
        g_writers = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < parts; i++) {
            ReadFileEx(
                existingFile,
                buff + offsets[i],
                nNumberOfBytesToRead,
                &overlapped[i],
                (LPOVERLAPPED_COMPLETION_ROUTINE)LPCompletionReading
            );
        }

        while (g_readers < parts)
            SleepEx(INFINITE, TRUE);

        for (int i = 0; i < parts; i++) {
            WriteFileEx(
                newFile,
                buff + offsets[i],
                nNumberOfBytesToRead,
                &overlapped[i],
                (LPOVERLAPPED_COMPLETION_ROUTINE)LPCompletionWriting);
        }
        while (g_writers < parts)
            SleepEx(INFINITE, TRUE);

        for (int i = 0; i < parts; i++) {
            overlapped[i].Offset += nNumberOfBytesToRead;
        }
        leftToCopy -= nNumberOfBytesToRead;
    } while (leftToCopy > 0);
    SetFilePointer(newFile, fileSize, NULL, FILE_BEGIN);
    SetEndOfFile(newFile);

    delete buff;
    delete overlapped;
}
```

Comment: I would suspect something like you are overloading the disk's controller. One way to test that would be to make multiple files and see how many requests on individual files it takes to get this behavior.

Comment: Parallel processing != faster processing. If you have a lot of I/Os going in parallel, the disk drive has to jump all over the place to satisfy those I/Os, which will be slower than just doing the I/Os in sequence. At least for traditional platter-based HDDs that have a physical read head that has to be moved around the platters. SDDs don't have that issue.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau: That's why I suspect the drive controller, even without needing to move a read head around it will still only have so much buffer capacity.

Comment: `while (g_readers < parts)
SleepEx(INFINITE, TRUE);` - this is wrong. you not need wait for all reads. when any read finished - you can just begin write this data, without wait on another reads

Comment: @RbMm as I mentioned in the post, I've tried starting writing right after reading was complete in reading completion routine, but it there was no measurable difference. 
I assume that the corresponding write was just performed right after read, and there was no time difference, since in the presented function the same thing is done, only in a different order.

Comment: @SergeevVladislav Could you show a mini, complete and reproducible code sample?

Comment: I have found an issue, it's a silly misstake.
In the line:

leftToCopy -= nNumberOfBytesToRead;
I should do this instead:

leftToCopy -= nNumberOfBytesToRead * parts;

Comment: @SergeevVladislav Does that solve this issue for you?